# StrongLoop ACL table doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, acl, strongloop

I succeed to generate all my models from my database. Then, I run the api by executing, 'node .' 
I'm able to see all my web services but when I try to try out a service, there is an 500 error saying to me that There is no ACL table. 
So, I open model-config.json and I saw that there were 4 models I didn't created before (User, AccessToken, ACL, RoleMapping and Role).
I would like to know if all these models has to exist in my database. And Do you know which properties I have to put in each table?
Thanks you in advance.

```
Error:
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'sed.ACL' doesn't exist",
    "code": "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE",
    "errno": 1146,
    "sqlState": "42S02",
    "index": 0,
    "stack": "Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'sed.ACL' doesn't exist\n [...]"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to automigrate these tables yourself. See:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/loopbackjs/automigrate$20default$20tables/loopbackjs/IiapgVVf-NQ/32yeCnNxBmIJ
- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/591.

Answer (score 5):

You need to migrate them yourself

1. Follow the basic procedure in [Attaching models to data sources](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Attaching-models-to-data-sources.html) to change from the in-memory data source to the  database you want to use.
2. Create `server/create-lb-tables.js` file with the following:

`var server = require('./server');
    var ds = server.dataSources.db;
    var lbTables = ['User', 'AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'Role'];
    ds.automigrate(lbTables, function(er) {
        if (er) throw er;
        console.log('Loopback tables [' - lbTables - '] created in ', ds.adapter.name);
        ds.disconnect();
    });`

3. Run the script manually:

`$ cd server`

`$ node create-lb-tables.js`

[For further details see loopback Documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-database-tables-for-built-in-models.html)

Comment: As on October 5, this works, thanks. I think it should be added the fact that in your step 2, second line, server.dataSources.db, this last db attribute refers to the name of the attribute "name" of the json "db" in datasources.json

Answer (score 0):

```
var server = require('./server');
    var ds = server.dataSources.db;
    var lbTables = ['User', 'AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'Role'];
    ds.automigrate(lbTables, function(er) {
        if (er) throw er;
        console.log('Loopback tables [' - lbTables - '] created in ', ds.adapter.name);
        ds.disconnect();
    });
```

Here 
`var ds = server.dataSources.db;`

`db` would be your database name, which you are using in **datasource.json** .

**database connection string:**

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "inventory": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "",
    "database": "inventory",
    "password": "root",
    "name": "inventory",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql"
  }
}
```

Here is my db name:

```
"database": "inventory"
```

Upadated code is

```
var server = require('./server');
    var ds = server.dataSources.inventory;
    var lbTables = ['User', 'AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'Role'];
    ds.automigrate(lbTables, function(er) {
        if (er) throw er;
        console.log('Loopback tables [' - lbTables - '] created in ', ds.adapter.name);
        ds.disconnect();
    });
```

shoot this code with independent saved file in directory with `node filename.js`
And it works.